# mysql calculate total amount of days absent

Tags: mysql

How would I calculate the total amount of days a user has been absent within a given date period?

This is the basic idea of how I think it would work but I cant get the total part to work.

```
SELECT total(from - until) FROM absences WHERE absences.user_id = 123
AND absence_date_until <= '1999-12-01' AND absence_date_from >=
'2000-12-01'


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `absences` (
  `absence_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `absence_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `absence_date_from` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `absence_date_until` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `absence_status` enum('PENDING','APPROVED') NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`absence_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(datediff(until, from) + 1) total_absences 
FROM   absences 
WHERE  absences.user_id = 123
       AND absence_date_until <= '1999-12-01' 
       AND absence_date_from  >= '2000-12-01'
```

Comment: This works perfect thanks. How come we need the `+1` can you explain why this part is needed?

Comment: DATEDIFF will give the difference between two dates, so if you have '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-02', the difference between the dates is 1. However that would be two days missed. So you would always need to add one to get the number of days absent.

Answer (score 0):

select datediff() im mysql

```
SELECT datediff(absence_date_from- absence_date_until) 
FROM absences WHERE absences.user_id = 123
AND absence_date_until <= '1999-12-01' 
AND absence_date_from >=  '2000-12-01'
```